# Format a portion of a string in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a string that is produced in a SQL Server function and it is returned like this:

```
          Ouseph MM, Li J, Chen HZ, Pécot T, Wenzel P, Thompson JC, Comstock 
          G, Chokshi V, Byrne M, Forde B, Chong JL, Huang K, Machiraju R, de 
          Bruin A, Leone G (2012) Atypical E2F repressors and activators 
          coordinate placental development. <i>Dev Cell</i>. 22(4):849-62 
          PMCID:PMC3483796
```

What I need to do it to bold with HTML tags a couple of the names that are stored in another table. The names could be:

```
        Leone GW
        Leone G
        Thompson J
        Thompson JC
```

This is the different ways that the names could exist. Do I need to create a cursor and loop? Then I also have the problem of names with one initial or both.  In this example I need to replace `Leone G` with `<b>Leone G</b>` and `Thompson JC` with `<b>Thompson JC</b>`

Any help or suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Show us what have you done till now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one quick approach... essentially a tokenized substitution.

Note: You would have to migrate this into a UDF if you wanted to apply this technique to an entire table.

> **EDIT:**

You may notice the CROSS JOIN in the subquery.  Here you would have to add any expected trailing delimiter

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Leone GW')
,('Leone G')
,('Thompson J')
,('Thompson JC')


Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Ouseph MM, Li J, Chen HZ, Pécot T, Wenzel P, Thompson JC, Comstock G, Chokshi V, Byrne M, Forde B, Chong JL, Huang K, Machiraju R, de Bruin A, Leone G (2012) Atypical E2F repressors and activators coordinate placental development. <i>Dev Cell</i>. 22(4):849-62 PMCID:PMC3483796'

Select @S=Replace(@S,MapFrom,MapTo)
 From  (
        Select MapFrom = SomeCol+suff
              ,MapTo   = '<b>'+SomeCol+'</b>'+suff
         From  @YourTable B1
         Cross Join (values (' ')
                           ,(',')
                           ,('.')
                    ) B2 (suff)
       ) A

Select @S
```

**Returns**

Ouseph MM, Li J, Chen HZ, Pécot T, Wenzel P, **Thompson JC** Comstock G, Chokshi V, Byrne M, Forde B, Chong JL, Huang K, Machiraju R, de Bruin A, **Leone G**(2012) Atypical E2F repressors and activators coordinate placental development. *Dev Cell*. 22(4):849-62 PMCID:PMC3483796

Comment: Note: **Thompson J**C. - the `C` is not bolded.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Great catch!  Didn't even look

Comment: Yeah, I guess the problem is that you do the replace for the shorter name first. I've tried to play with it for a minute but didn't get it right so I thought I'll just let you know :-)

Comment: Fantastic concept but like Zohar said C is not bolded.  If I reverse the names in the list so JC comes before C then it is bolded twice.  Once including the C and once without.

Comment: @user1314159 easy fix.. one moment

Comment: Super Cool-- How do I give you 2 check marks--  :)  Just totally awesome

Comment: Now you have to also fix the delimiter before, not only after :-) c u in 2525 :-) +1 from me as well

Comment: @user1314159 Happy to help.  Thanks for the grin

Comment: I knew I'm not the only one that remembers all the not important details in life :-)

Comment: Hi, great solution! Happily plused it.